# Android P - KeyStore exception android.os.ServiceSpecificException: (code 7)

Tags: java, android, android-keystore, android-9.0-pie

Android P logs a weird exception when I try to read the certificate I imported into the KeyStore from outside. I do the following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        //cert variable is a string with my self signed certificate
        saveX509Certificate(cert, "example");
        String key = encrypt("example");
        Log.d("tag", key);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void saveX509Certificate(String certificate, String certificateAlias) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    X509Certificate myCert = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory
            .getInstance("X.509")
            .generateCertificate(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(certificate.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    keyStore.load(null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry(certificateAlias, myCert);
}

public String encrypt(String keyAlias) throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null);

    Certificate certificate = keyStore.getCertificate(keyAlias); //here's where the exception is thrown
    PublicKey publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();

    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

The code works well and returns my public key from the certificate so I'm fine with that, yet I got the following notification in logcat:

```
KeyStore exception
android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code 7)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1956)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
    at android.security.IKeystoreService$Stub$Proxy.get(IKeystoreService.java:786)
    at android.security.KeyStore.get(KeyStore.java:195)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetCertificate(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:144)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getCertificate(KeyStore.java:1120)
    at com.example.mat.myapplication.MainActivity.encrypt(MainActivity.java:65)
    at com.example.mat.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Have you ever experienced some of this or know what to do to get rid of this warning? I need to add that when I generate e.g. RSA key pair on the device, I do not get this warning when trying to retrieve a private key from KeyStore, it only happens with imported certificate from outside. Also, the code works well without the notification about KeyStore Exception in the previous versions of Android, that is Oreo, Nugat and Marshmallow.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to import a certificate into AndroidKeyStore?  AndroidKeyStore is for storing secrets, and certificates are not secret.

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you get any updates on it?

Comment: @SwapnilChaudhari I never found an answer for this question sadly. The good thing is, it does not crash application, it still works, I am able to use Public Key retrieved this way. So I gave it up for now and not looking at it any longer. One day I will check if it happens on Android Q as well.

Comment: @Matt please let us know about your test on Android Q